# laravel pagination of nested query results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination, paginator

I want to create query to output all posts belongs to one category with pagination of posts.
I did like that, but anyway on output I have simple Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection of posts without paginator.
How to do that?

In my models I have relations 
One category hasMany Posts.
One post belongsTo one Category.

```
    public function getItemWithPostsWithSimplePaginator($slug, $perPage = null)
    {
        $columns = ['id', '_lft', '_rgt', 'parent_id', 'title', 'slug', 'icon', 'description', 'image', 'metatitle', 'metakey', 'metadesc'];

        $postcolumns = ['title','slug','category_id','image','fulltext','created_at'];

        $result = $this
            ->startConditions()
            ->whereSlug($slug)
            ->select($columns)
            ->with(['posts' => function($query) use(&$postcolumns, &$perPage) {
                $query->select($postcolumns)
                      ->wherePublished(true)
                      ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                      ->simplePaginate($perPage);
                }])
            ->first();

        return $result;
    }
```

If I do dd I can see in output collection with 11 Posts, though `$perPage =10` and total number of posts belongs to this category is 24. So it works partly.
The only thing I miss is paginator object.

If I replace `simplePaginate` with `paginate` I can see collection with 10 Posts, but anyway normal collection without paginator.

```
App\Models\NewsCategory {#838 ▼
  +timestamps: false
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "news_categories"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:12 [▶]
  #original: array:12 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "posts" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#905 ▼
      #items: array:11 [▼
        0 => App\Models\NewsPost {#925 ▶}
        1 => App\Models\NewsPost {#926 ▶}
        2 => App\Models\NewsPost {#927 ▶}
        3 => App\Models\NewsPost {#928 ▶}
        4 => App\Models\NewsPost {#929 ▶}
        5 => App\Models\NewsPost {#930 ▶}
        6 => App\Models\NewsPost {#931 ▶}
        7 => App\Models\NewsPost {#932 ▶}
        8 => App\Models\NewsPost {#933 ▶}
        9 => App\Models\NewsPost {#934 ▶}
        10 => App\Models\NewsPost {#935 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #pending: null
  #moved: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions you can try is to use **setRelation()** method.

```
$result = $result->setRelation(
    'posts', 
    YourPostModel::select($postcolumns)
        ->wherePublished(true)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
        ->simplePaginate($perPage)
);
```

Comment: you mean `setRelation()` instead of `with()` method? I just tried and this gives me error `Call to undefined method Kalnoy\Nestedset\QueryBuilder::setRelation()`

Comment: I also tried to comment `with` and queue `setRelation()` after `first()`. It is just give `output #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "posts" => Closure($query) {#803 ▼` even without post items inside

Comment: It seems that you are using kalnoy/nestedset package and this package does not have setRelation method on their QueryBuilder

Comment: This is not correct. 1) If in my model I remove `use Kalnoy\Nestedset\NodeTrait;` and try **setRelation()**, then I have error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::setRelation()`

Comment: 2)  If I comment `with` and queue `setRelation()` after first(). It is just give output `#observables: [] #relations: array:1 [▼ "posts" => Closure($query) {#788 ▼` even without post items inside. Just like I have using kalnoy/nestedset package

Comment: `
->setRelation(
    'posts', function($query) {
    $query->select($postColumns)
        ->wherePublished(true)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
        ->simplePaginate($perPage);
    });
`

Comment: And your code without `function($query) {}` just give error  **Undefined variable: query**

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you should replace **$query** with the I believe Post model so it will look like this for example Post::select()...

Comment: Also you can check that setRelation model exists https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_setRelation

Comment: This code is working. But I cannot understand why `with` doesn't give same result. What I don't like in this solution is that I need to call PostModel directly. And in Category repository I want to avoid that.

Comment: I think there should be solution to avoid that, I will try out something else and let you know if it works. You can always call it like **$this->posts()** for example inside your NewsCategory class